How to access the filesystem in a sandboxed app on macOS?
Imagine a sandboxed app on macOS (thus, App-story-savvy)  where you can drag-and-drop files onto, which would subsequently be processed and written back. Obviously, the app needs write permissions outside the sandbox. How can I do that?
To be more concise: The app will process these files by invoking a shell script. Executing the shell script is easy, but it needs its permissions elevated accordingly, too, which can be a security concern. Is this possible at all?

This doesn't look like it's requesting off-site resources. The OP is asking for documentation (probably Apple documentation) on how to accomplish his goal. Seems like a legit request to me. I'm voting to re-open.

I'm not sure about the twist of invoking a shell script to process your files, but Apple added something called Security-scoped bookmarks to track files and folders that the user granted your app's access to. Take a look at the section https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional-video-applications/enabling-security-scoped-bookmark-and-url-access in Apple's docs.

Also take a look at entitlements like com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write

Solution: Anything the user chooses in a file selection dialog, will be added to the app’s sandbox. You need to present the user with a .fileImporter or the likes, so that the user can actively choose a folder. This folder, and its subfolders, will be temporarily added to the app’s sandbox.
However, doing this for every new app launch would be cumbersome. macOS lets you save the URL returned from the FileOpenPanel as a bookmark:
// directory -> URL returned from the .fileImporter
let bookmark = try directory.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope)
let gotAccess = bookmarkURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmark, forKey: "bookmark")

Subsequent app starts will have the same elevated permissions if you
var theBookmarkData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "bookmark")
var stale = false // Does the bookmark need a refresh?
var bookmarkURL = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: theBookmarkData!, options: .withSecurityScope, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale )
if stale {
    theBookmarkData = try bookmarkURL.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(theBookmarkData, forKey: "bookmark")
    bookmarkURL = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: theBookmarkData!, options: .withSecurityScope, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale )
}
let gotAccess = bookmarkURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
...

